# Move AWS EC2 snapshot from S3 to Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-glacier

I ran a full initial snapshot of an EC2 instance I don't see a need for in the forseeable future. I plan to terminate the instance later today and turn off the domain DNS for the site pointing to it.

I'm aware AWS stores snapshots on S3, but Glacier is cheaper. So as an alternative, can I set a lifecycle policy on the snapshot so it automatically moves to Glacier after a period of time? If so, how exactly can I do this since the S3 console doesn't provide access to snapshot buckets? (The shorter the time-to-moving the better in my case -- I want the cheap, long-term storage)

Once moved, I'll want to delete the snapshot from S3. There will be no more incremental changes or snapshots; this is it.

Please be specific with CLI commands or steps if you don't mind -- I'm not terribly familiar with AWS yet.

Comment: If your EC2 server was EBS backed, then you have no direct access to the snapshots in S3 and you can't move them to Glacier.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way to do this. EBS snapshots are stored in S3, but that is a “behind the scenes” implementation detail. The snapshots are not visible in an S3 bucket, not are they exposed via the S3 API. So you cannot move them to Glacier.

A third party tool called N2WS that recently announced support for offloading snapshots to Glacier at AWS re:Invent 2018. However it stores the snapshots in its own format. It is running “on top of” AWS rather than doing it natively. 
http://n2ws.com/